# Gnuplot color bar

Tags: dictionary, plot, colors, gnuplot, block

I have to plot the solution of some parabolic pde with gnuplot. Since parabolic pde's solution changes with time I've printed the solution at different times with C++ code; each solution is written in a file "pde.n.dat", where n is between 1 and the number of files printed. My solution is something like this:

```
x0   y0   f(x0,y0)
x0   y1   f(x0,y1)

x1   y0   f(x1,y0)
x1   y1   f(x1,y1)
```

I've plotted my solutions with gnuplot using the following script (I put it in a "file.gp"):

```
fname="pde.".n.".dat"
set pm3d map
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange[0:1]
set palette defined
splot fname
print n
n=n+1;
pause 0.01
if(n<=100)reread
```

and I loaded with the script

```
n=1
load "file.gp"
```

The script works but the colour map is set every time I plot a solution. For example at time 0 I have this colour map (between 0 and 1):

[solution at time 0 (colour map between 0 and 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoLDW.png)

For my solution at time 1 I have a different colour map

[solution at time 1 (colour map between 0.01 and 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fDel.png)

Is it possible to block color map on specific colours in order to have the same colour map for all plots?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37745891/2604213

Comment: I tried

set cbrange [MIN:MAX]

and it works! Thank you very much!